# I am getting the error "The requested resource isn't a valid image for /public/logoicon/logoOrange.png received text/html; charset=utf-8"

Tags: javascript, html, css, browser, next.js

I am getting an error while trying to add a [PNG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Network_Graphics) or [SVG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalable_Vector_Graphics) file to my code. What is my mistake is or what do I have to change to get it working?

```
import Head from 'next/head'
import Image from 'next/image'
import styles from '../styles/Home.module.css'

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <div className={styles.container}>

      <Head>
        <title>Maintenance</title>
        <meta name="description" content="This Website is in Maintenance Mode" />
        <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
      </Head>
      <div className={styles.main}>
     <h1 className={styles.h1}>This website is currently in</h1>
     <break></break>
     <h1 className={styles.h2}>Maintenance Mode.</h1>
     <Image
            src="/public/logoicon/logoOrange.png"
            alt="server and database with broken cable"
            width={77}
            height={33}
        />
     <p className={styles.p}>©2022 Karlo-Hosting.com</p>
     </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

My code is above.

Comment: `received text/html; charset=utf-8` is a strong indicator that your server returned an HTML document, instead of an actual image - most likely that of your 404 error page. Have you checked how the request got answered, using your browser dev tools?

Comment: If you're referencing an image served from the public folder your image source should be `src="/logoicon/logoOrange.png"`. See https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/static-file-serving.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the server sends you a response thats say "received text/html; charset=utf-8", try to analyse the error. You can see that the server says *"Here is your requested text/HTML content that has the UTF-8 format"*.

Check if the source of the image is correct. And if the image exists and try to check what text/HTML content the file server sends back to you.

Answer (score 33):

Solution 1.
this error is in terminal right, so
'public' folder is exposed at root level, so you need not specify the public folder

try this -
src="/logoicon/logoOrange.png"

instead of -
src="/public/logoicon/logoOrange.png"

Solution 2.still if you get 400 bad request error in console

then its a generic client error

check for->
a) URL string syntax
b) corrupted cache and cookie
c) check if image is too big
d) check for any whitespaces in naming folder

Comment: This helped me. I am new with Next js and I was using public foolder along with my image path in image src.
Thanks

Answer (score 16):

Also just starting picking up Next.js and was baffled by why my images were not being displayed.
After changing the format multiple times and checking the source. It appear that the images are actually hosted in the public folder

**The solution to my image problem:**

So adding images in the following directory:

`public/images/[place image file]`

This is what my problem was. Hope this helps someone else.

Answer (score 7):

Simply remove the /public portion before your image name.
The public folder is exposed, and automatically searched through and understood by NEXT.JS.

So make /public/test.jpg => /test.jpg

Answer (score 6):

try using directly "/" instead of "/public" like this

```
<Image src={`/image.png`} alt="something" height={150} width={200}/>
```

Answer (score 3):

So the only thing that works since Next13's Image changes is a set up like this. Note that they have also opted to remove the objectFit props in favour for styles instead - I don't really get the rationale behind this as it feels a bit regressive!

But anyway, I hope this helps some of you. You dont have to call it 'imageAsset' this is just an example - call it what you like as long as it's in your public folder it'll work :)

I thought I would type out a bit of a example as I know some people that come here are new to Next/React and might not fully understand the implementation just yet.

**NOTE:** removing `/public/` from the image src or import doesn't work for all cases as your images may not be directly in the public folder - like below my images are in a subfolder in that directory. Therefore removing `/public/` will **not** work.

```
import Image from "next/image"
import imageAsset from '/public/images/your-image-asset.webp'

export default function Component() {
  return (
    <>
      <Image src={imageAsset} width={1920} height={1080} style={{objectFit: 'cover', objectPosition: 'center'}} />
    </>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're using nextjs 13 and run in to this problem you have to import the image as an object from the public folder for example:

```
import placeHolder from '../../../../../public/placeholder.jpg';
```

and use it in the Image component like this:

```
<Image
  width={120}
  height={60}
  src={placeHolder}
  alt="brand"
 />
```

you can also use style for example if you want to set a background image in a div you can do this:

```
<div style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${placeHolder.src})`}}>

 </div>
```

Answer (score 3):

if you are using middleware the problem is in [ matcher ] you need to pass the parameters for it to ignore

```
export const config = {
  matcher: [
    /*
     * Match all request paths except for the ones starting with:
     * - api (API routes)
     * - _next/static (static files)
     * - _next/image (image optimization files)
     * - favicon.ico (favicon file)
     */
    '/((?!api|_next/static|_next/image|favicon.ico).*)',
  ],
}
```

_next/static|_next/image -> they ignore the images and with that it stops giving error and returns 404 [ text/plain ]

https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/middleware

Answer (score 1):

For me another process was running on `port` 3000. You can find the process by running the command below in your Mac Terminal.

```bash
$ lsof -i :3000
```

Afterwards, you can kill the process from Activity Monitor. In my case another instance of NodeJS was utilising port 3000.

Comment: @starball NextJS development server is powered by NodeJS or at least mine was. I'm using NextJS 12 which uses a rust based compiler (SWC). I hope that answers your question.

Answer (score 1):

importing it like `import img from '/public/[your image here]'` seems to be working.

Answer (score 1):

Worked for me:
place all the images in public/(assets or images) folder then import the images into a index.js file
like this :

```
import imagename from './imagename.gif'
import imagename from './imagename.jpg'
import imagename from './imagename.png'

export{
    imagename, imagename, imagename
}
```

then import the needed image from the projects/assets/index.js
like this:

```
import { imagename } from '../public/assets'
```

use it in Image like this:

```
<Image src={imagename} />
```

Answer (score 0):

Faced this issue today. Seems like a problem with next/dynamic which would not load the image properly. Not a ethical solution but not dynamically importing your component with the image in it seems to fix it for me.

Answer (score 0):

As I just experienced. Probably because the basePath located in next.config.js has changed.

Try to set basePath to default (`basePath: '',`)

Answer (score 0):

For me, I tried almost every solution mentioned by all contributors. None worked so I switched from the Next.js `Image` tag to the HTML `img` tag, but removed the public directory and put immediately the `/image.png` and it works dynamically when loaded.

Answer (score 0):

I include my image in public directory after that I used below code. It's working for me.

```
<Image src={'/abc.png'} alt="/" width='125' height='50' />
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error in production build when I tried to upload an image through an input, although everything worked fine in the dev mode. Upon studying, I found out that's because the public folder is inaccessible during the production build and in order to load the newly generated image, you can make use of services like Amazon S3.. hope it helps someone.